# How to detect a sine wave signal to trigger a logic gate?

Tags: operational-amplifier, flipflop, detection, voltage-detector

I need a way to detect a signal input and then output it as a logic high. The signal input has a 40 kHz frequency and it's a sine-shaped signal. The amplitude is not sure, could be from 12 V to 1 V.

It should produce a logic high within 59 us of the start of the AC signal

Comment: You need a constant 1, which I can only interpret as a logic high, but then you say it would be a clock? How would a constant DC value be a clock? Do you instead need to convert a sine input into a square clock suitable for logic?

Comment: I don't understand what it would mean to convert _any_ kind of signal to "a constant positive DC signal." A constant positive DC signal doesn't carry any information at all, so what would it mean to convert something to a constant positive DC signal?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I am using jk flip flop to loop some numbers. I want it stop looping and show that number when I get that Sin signal. That's why I want to convert the Sin signal to a constant 1 as cloak signal. Sorry I didn't mention it clearly.

Comment: Why do you need an op amp for bridge rectifier? But anyway, please describe what exactly you are trying to do, instead of trying to solve that with a specific way which may be wrong. What sine it is, where does it come from, what is frequency and amplitude, why it must trigger a jk flip-flop, what is the purpose of the whole thing? If you have a circuit diagram, show it.

Comment: @jjk Ok, I think I see what you want. Is this correct: You want a way to detect a sine signal input and output a logic high, which will be used by some down-stream circuit. If this is correct, please update your question to reflect this. Perhaps use the diagram tools to create a block diagram or something.

Comment: Oh that's exactly what I want! Sorry I am still learning and I didn't mean to cause confusion. I will update my question right now!

Comment: Ok, how quickly the output must go high when sine wave starts, and how quickly the output must go low when sine wave stops? So sine wave can be max +/- 12V and min +/- 1V? Or does the sine wave have a DC bias?

Comment: Hi ideally I want the out put to go high in  1/17000 second when we get this sin signal. We don't necessarily need to consider the go low part. When it goes high I could consider it always high until I manually shut it down. The amplitude is between 1V and 12V, so the sine wave could be  max +/-12V and  min +/- 1V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit should give you the general idea.

The first half is an ac to dc converter which produces a dc signal which has a level equal to the pk to pk value of the ac sine waveform minus two diode drops. The op amp is configured as a non-inverting schmitt trigger which produces a positive output when its input goes above a certain threshold as determined by the values of R3,R4,R5 & R6. So the output goes high when the input sine wave is present.

Perhaps use a rail to rail output op amp with a supply voltage equal to the supply voltage of the following logic devices.

You will need to adjust the components' values to cater for your particular situation.

[image: Sig processing]

Comment: Oh thank you so much! It solves my problem! I been thinking about it for a few days!

Answer (score 0):

> the frequency of my Sin signal exceeds the frequency limit for diodes in my lab.

Uh what?  A diode is not a slow device.  If you cannot use any kind of rectification (and for rectification, there really isn't anything faster than some kind of diode), you are mostly down to putting your signal through a resistor or similar and measuring when it gets warm.  Even then, at frequencies exceeding the capabilities of diodes in your lab, getting the signal to the resistor may be an adventure since mere wires behave icky at microwave frequencies and beyond.

For some frequencies there are special detection devices, like photodiodes that convert photoquants into electrical charge, again bypassing rectification by converting entire energy packets into unipolar signals.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I think you are right. I might misunderstood my instructor.

Comment: PN diodes can be pretty slow. That's one of the reasons Schottky diodes are so popular, in addition to their lower voltage drop, and the entire reason FREDs exist. But 40 kHz is definitely not high enough to cause problems with even the slowest PN diodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method using a monostable multivibrator and BJT:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! Your reply inspired me!

Answer (score 0):

You should add your specifications to the question, and not just in your comments. So there is a 40 kHz sine wave (25 us period) which may have an amplitude of +/- 1V to +/- 12V. You want to detect it within 59 us, so it can be triggered on just the positive portion. Here is a simple two-transistor circuit that can accomplish this.

[image: Sine Wave Detector]

If you want the output to reset when the signal is no longer present, just add a capacitor and resistor:

[image: Sine Wave Detector With Reset]

A pull-up resistor can be added to trigger at a lower voltage:

[image: Sensitivity increased]

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for explaining each steps. I really appreciate this circuit with only basic lab equipment.

Comment: If the answers are valuable to you, please upvote them. And whichever is best, please choose it as the preferred answer. It helps to build reputation and indicates a solution that might help others with similar needs.